# PHP MYSQL Attendance Limit Once a Day

Tags: php, mysql

I am Beginner in php and i am making the project on attendance system but i don't know how to code for single-day attendance for the student once in a day. I didn't get the appropriate result.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

    if($_SESSION['user']==true){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

              $sql= ("INSERT INTO `student_attendence`(`Student_id`,`Date`,`Attendence`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user']."','$date','$attendence') ");

                if(count($error)==0){
                    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                        echo "Error ".mysqli_error($conn);

                    }
                    else{
                        header("location:studentlogin.php");
                    }
                }        
        }
    }   
    else{
        header("location:studentlogin.php");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code, what the appropriate result should be and what you got instead? That way we can help you faster. Therefore please edit your question and add these infos. Thank you

Comment: I said, edit your question. Don't add your code in the comments.

Comment: ok thanks sir. but in edit i already pasted the code.

Comment: Remember to add "```" at the beginning and end of your code to actually display it as text if it's HTML or PHP.

Comment: Can you also add the result you're getting and the result you actually want?

Comment: okay, thanks sir got it. actually I am a beginner in stack overflow also.

Comment: It's alright, don't sweat it. Everyone does mistakes at first but what's important is to learn from those mistakes.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I  am not able to attendance once a day of the user. Database every time store attendance of every user every time

Comment: Why the alternate spellings of 'attendance'?

Comment: Also, see about prepared and bound queries

Comment: By mistake, after that, I didn't change the spellings. OK thanks a lot, I will see about prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase one more attribute in DB table which is **date**.
So whenever you insert a new attendence insert today's date also.
Always check for today's date must not present in DB before inserting the attendence.
So while inserting the attendence in DB, you must have to check first -

```
If today's date is already present in DB
   true : display message(today's attendence has already taken).

   false: save the attendence in DB.
```

> Note -
>   MySQL's default DATE format is **YYYY-MM-DD**.

This is the quick method you can impliment.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I will do this as you said. Thanks, again

Comment: Think briefly again, and try to do it again, it must work. Implement this algorithm by debuging your code then you can easily understand where did you stuck.

Comment: Thank you sir I solved this with a unique index in MySQL. And it works. Thanks a lot, sir